# Using AngularJS Jqlite, how can I find the first child of an element that is of a certain element type?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-selectors, jqlite

In my AngularJS directive, I want to apply focus to the first child of type `<pre>` of the last child of type `<div>`.

That is if my document looks like this:

```
<div main-div>
     <div>
     </div>
     <div>
          <div>
               <pre></pre>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div>
          <div>
               <pre the-one></pre>
          </div>
     </div>
```

the `<pre>` it should select is the last one, with an attribute `the-one`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did my answer below address your question?

Comment: @NewDev pretty much. It led me on the right path. So I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have the structure above as a jqLite element (however you get it a hold of it), you could do the following:

```
var divs = element.children().find("div");
var theOne;
if (divs.length > 0){
  theOne = angular.element(divs[divs.length-1]).find("pre");
}
```